# Is there any standard PHP browser sniffer code?

Tags: php, browser, sniffing

I need a simple, reliable browser sniffer to customize some styles for chrome.
I searched for a PHP browser sniffer, but all that came up seemed to be a whole bunch of personal, non-standard scripts on php user forums, which baffled me as php is such an old language and browser sniffing is such a ubiquitous web developing technique, that one or two standard robust browser sniffers without extra bells and whistles should be out there, i couldn't find them.

I don't want to use JavaScript due to unreliable activation/presence.

I'd basically would want a more or less official website/tutorial based on standard php sniffing code, as opposed to 'customized'. One that sniffs browsers, and that's that. (can't get why there seemed to be so many different versions in php, in JavaScript there's a standard technique).

Or if you have a good one that works, and won't mind sharing it.

Comment: "Robust" and "browser sniffer" do not belong in the same sentence. (Unless it's a negation.)

Comment: I meant one that simply works reliably, which is easy in JavaScript as long as JavaScript is active on the client. The impression I got from my limited research is that PHP browser sniffing is still in the testing beta stage, from all the different versions I saw.  I mean PHP ,has standard form handling, database handling, but no standard basic browser detection? Am I wrong? Hope so, unless i'm high.

Comment: Generally, all PHP (or any server-side code) has available is the User-Agent string, which is notorious for being the biggest pack of lies in six counties. Microsoft Edge, for example, claims to be at least six different browsers, and *all* browser vendors for years have recommended that browser sniffing be abandoned. There is basically never any need for it, except to serve customized download ads for browsers you want to peddle.

Comment: So there's no reliable way in PHP? So I need to use JavaScript? Clearly, browser detection can be used for css customization, as there are those -web-kit styles and others, like firefox specific.

Comment: The usual way to use vendor prefixes (which are *also* deprecated, these days; no new prefixed properties will be defined) is to simply stack them all up together in the same file. No detection.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into vendor prefixes.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified that I need to target just one property in Chrome, it seems the vendor prefix would target other browsers as well. I just need to target Chrome for now. I might delete this question and re-ask another more specifically, if recommended.

Comment: I'd recommend [edit]ing it instead. Deleted questions can count towards question-bans.